# Design Pattern for monitoring multiple objects

Tags: design-patterns

I have a multi threaded application, with one thread which owns multiple objects - updates them periodically. Another thread has to access these objects and uses it for some operation. Which pattern would suit my need?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the use-case?

Comment: Basically I need to monitor multiple sensors from a thread and access the sensor values from another thread to perform a background task like checking it for some threshold crossing.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [Observer Pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html)

In nutshell, its like - Your main thread would listen for 'events' generated by sensor threads. So, the steps could be:

A) You sensor thread expose a method, to let the main thread register for the event. Use an interface approach for this.

B) As soon as data changes within the sensor, it will call a method on the main thread (note that it has its reference in step A). This way, the main thread will come to know that its time for action.

Comment: Thanks. Even my first inclination was towards Observer pattern. But when we look at it, Observer pattern makes life easier in case of multiple observers on a single subject. Whereas Im looking for something where there are multiple subjects and a single observer - like in my case there multiple sensors and a main thread from where I would like to aggregate all the sensors values and may be log it in a file periodically.

Comment: If you want to fetch sensor data periodically (irrespective of it changed or not); simply iterate on the collection of sensors at pre-defined time.. Use a simple Java timer which will invoke a method in main thread and method will collect the sensor data. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_schedule_period.htm   .... Let me know, if this is the solutions, I will update the solution.

Comment: The Observer pattern is still appropriate in this case.

Comment: @neontapir  - I agree with you, Observer pattern incorporate some kind of event to be triggered; which can be a timer (if data needs to be collected periodically). If this is what the OP needs; implementing this with interface approach will bring near to Observer Pattern - Timer thread generating the event, and main thread acting on the event.

Answer (score 1):

In the Observer pattern you will have a notify method

```
    public void Notify()
    {
        this.observers.ForEach(x => x.Update());
    }
```

What you want, is for the observers, (you can have just one observer) to know about each subject so then it can log the values.  So, you could pass the subject to the Update method.

```
    public void Notify()
    {
        this.observers.ForEach(x => x.Update(this));
    }
```

and, in the observer's Update method you can log and check for threshold crossing

```
    public void Update(Subject subject)
    {
        if(subject.Value > 5)
            Log.Write(subject.Value)
    }
```

You can have multiple subjects subscribing to the same Observer object.

```
        subject1.Subscribe(observer1);
        subject2.Subscribe(observer1);
```